When returning an object from an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, an object with ValueKind property is returned instead
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API method which returns this object:
return new ApiResult
           {
                Success = true,
                Data = new
                {
                    profile = usuario.Data,
                    workerId = trabajador.TrabajadorId
                }
           }

where usuario.Data is an object of type ProfileInfo.
When I receive that object in the client, profile property is a JSON object with just 1 property called ValueKind.
I have added this in Program.cs file:
builder.Services
    .AddRazorPages()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });

to change from System.Text.Json to Newtonsoft Json.NET instead, but the problem persists.
Any help?
EDIT: as an ugly workaround, I have serialized the profile object using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize and then deserialized again using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json) using the following extension methods I created:
return new ApiResult
{
    Success = true,
    Data = new
    {
        profile = usuario.Data.FromObject().ToObject<ProfileInfo>(),
        workerId = trabajador.TrabajadorId
    }
};

I hope you can point me to a real solution for this.

Would suspect that you are defining the usuario.Data as JsonElement type instead of ProfileInfo. If my statement is true, then either you should change it to ProfileInfo type, or use the JObject if this property is supported for a dynamic JSON oject.

Your problem is the same as Problem #2 from this answer to .NET Serializing a complex Dto to JSON string.  Somewhere you are deserializing to dynamic or object with System.Text.Json, which deserializes to its Document Object Model type JsonElement, then serializing with Json.NET which does not support this model.  You need to use one serializer consistently, or switch to using a fully typed data model.

@YongShun no.... I have not dealt with Json objects. They are all C# objects. Conversion is made automatically when the API REST method returns.
